# Firebase, is it possible to place verifyPhoneNumber outside activity without passing activity reference to it?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, phone-number

I'm trying to implement Firebase phone number authentication. Official docs says that I need to call

```
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
    60,                 // Timeout duration
    TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
    this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
    mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
```

And pass my activity reference for callback binding.

There is another overloaded method in docs, which accepts `TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD` (the Executor used to call the `OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks` callbacks), instead of activity ref.

That's what I needed. In this case

```
phoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phone,
        1,
        TimeUnit.MINUTES,
        TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,
        callbacks,
        resendingToken
);
```

The code works perfectly. But the problem is: callbacks continue their work in a background infinitely long. I didn't find any methods in the documentation to stop these callbacks.

So, how can I manually remove these callbacks, when I don't need them anymore?

Comment: hey found any solution?

Comment: Is there any solution available for this?

Comment: PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                PhoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
                60,                 // Timeout duration
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                (Activity) TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,    //Activity (for callback binding)
                mCallbacks);        //OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD instead.

```
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber, // Phone number to verify
    60, // Timeout duration
    TimeUnit.SECONDS, // Unit of timeout
    TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD, // Executor
    verifyNumberCallback
)
```